# Userlist from facebook users for variables on android firebase?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is this the best way to create a user list from facebook users to hold variables on firebase? I want each user to have a few int variables, tokens, spins, and biggestWin. but the `createUser` method doesn't seem to add any data to the firebase, and doesnt seem to work well with the facebook code. It always toasts "not created"

```
public void createUser(String mEmail, String mProvide){

    Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://luckycashslots.firebaseio.com/data/");
    Firebase userRef = rootRef.child("users");

    userRef.setValue(mAuthData.getUid());

    Firebase newRef = new Firebase("https://luckycashslots.firebaseio.com/data/users/" + mAuthData.getUid() + "/");
    Firebase tokRef = newRef.child("tokens");
    Firebase spinRef = newRef.child("spins");

    newRef.setValue(mAuthData.getProvider());

    Tokens token = new Tokens("100");
    Spins spin = new Spins(55);

    tokRef.setValue(token);
    //spinRef.setValue(spin);

    rootRef.createUser(mEmail, mProvide , new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes-UID=" + result.get("Uid") , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an email+password user or authenticating a user with Facebook does indeed not store any data about that user in the Firebase Database.

If you want to store user data in the database, see the section on [storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing) in the Firebase documentation.